# How to delete large file in Grails using Apache camel

Tags: apache, file, grails, apache-camel

I am using Grails 2.5. We are using Camel. I have folder called GateIn. In this delay time is 3minutes. So Every 3minutes , it will look into the folder for file. If the file exists, it will start to process. If the file is processed within 3 minutes, file get deleted automatically. Suppose my file takes 10minutes,file is not deleted.Again and again, it process the same file. How to make file get deleted whether it is small or bulk file. I have used noop= true to stop reuse of file. But i want to delete the file too once it is preocessed. Please give me some suggestion for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the file size using camel file language and decide what to do next.

Usually, in this kind of small interval want to process a large size of file, it will be better to have another process zone (physical directory), you have to move the file after immediately consuming it to that zone.

You can have a separate logic or camel route to process the file. After successful process, you can delete or do appropriate step according to your requirement. Hope it helps !!